# Wordpress > htaccess > custom search url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with mod_rewrite and can't seem to fix it. I'm trying to do the following things:

1. Redirect the default /?s=*search-term* to zoeken/*search-term* for userfriendly urls
2. Internal rewrite / passtrough zoeken/*search-term* -> search/*search-term*, so the url stays zoeken/search-term

Could you give me some pointers or advice?

.htaccess

```
# basics
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project/project.nl/
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #
    # ?s=term -> zoeken/term
    # wordpress has permalink search for searching
    #
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ zoeken/%1/? [NC,R,L]

    # Internal rewrite zoeken -> search
    #
    RewriteRule project/project.nl/zoeken/(.+)$ search/$1/? [NC,PT,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What should happen if I search for `some/test`?

Comment: Your example would be picked up by the last block (#begin wordpress - #end wordpress) and handled by index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems were in leading slash and not adding index.php and L flag to result.
Here is the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ search/%1? [NC,L,R]

# Rewrite localized search url -> search/term 
# 
RewriteRule ^zoeken/(.+)$ index.php/search/$1 [NC,L]
```